# Choose specific database for mysql gtid replication

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-replication, myisam

Is it possible to choose a specific database for replication using MySQL GTID? I'm running MySQL server 5.6, and it has many databases, some are MyISAM, the rest are InnoDB. I just wanna replicate ONE InnoDB database to a slave. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your my.cnf on the master:

```
binlog_do_db = database_name
```